# Julian Date Format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I remove the year in the output of my query:

```
SELECT datepart(year, GETDATE()) * 1000 + datepart(DY, GETDATE()) as Julian
```

Output: 2018107 (Apr. 17, 2018)

Expected Output: 107 (Apr. 17, 2018)

Comment: What is wrong with `SELECT datepart(DY, GETDATE())`, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT datepart(DY, GETDATE())
```